# Props from Stateful component calling Functional component changes type

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. I want to render an array in a functional component called from a stateful component.

What am I doing that causes the Array in the class component to be changed to an object in the called component?

```
class Vehicles extends Component {
  state = { vehicles: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/vehicles')
      .then((Response) => Response.json())
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({ vehicles: res });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  render() {
    console.log('Stateful Component:', this.state.vehicles);
    console.log(this.state.vehicles instanceof Array);
    if (this.state.vehicles.length > 0) {
      return <VehicleList props={this.state.vehicles} />;
    } else return null;
  }
}

const VehicleList = (props) => {
  console.log('Functional Component:', props);
  console.log('Functional Component:', typeof props);
  console.log(props instanceof Array);
  return (
        ...
  );
};
export default Vehicles;
```

The console shows:

```
Stateful Component: (37) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
true 
Functional Component: {props: Array(37)} 
Functional Component: object 
false
```

Comment: Vehicle array will be accessible through props.props in your functional component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes because `props` of the component is always an object. See this line

```
<VehicleList props={this.state.vehicles} />;
```

You are setting setting `props` as `this.state.vehicles` but you are setting `props` as property of original `props`. So you can access it using `props.props`. However this will cause confusion due to similar names instead use

```
<VehicleList vehicles={this.state.vehicles} />;
```

And then in you Functional Component

```
const VehicleList = (props) => {
  const {vehicles} = props
  console.log('Functional Component:', vehicles);
  console.log('Functional Component:', vehicles);
  console.log(vehicles instanceof Array);
  return (
        ...
  );
};
```